# WPF UserControl border blinking when moving mouse outside during command processing

Tags: wpf, listview, focus, controls

I have written a WPF UserControl (let's called it ContainerUserControl), inside it it uses other UserControl (let's call it OstUserControl) which I build from another project. Within the ContainerUserControl, I have a RibbonGroup hosting bunch of RibbonButtons. The OtsUserControl can respond to user mouse clicks on a toggle button inside and runs the same code if user clicks a corresponding RibbonButton.

However the odd thing is: If I click the RibbonButton (which is outside of the border of the OtsUserControl), there is flickering around the boundary of OtsUserControl; 
If I click a toggle button inside OtsUserControl and don't move the mouse outside the OtsUserControl, there is NO flickering;
If I click a toggle button inside OtsUserControl and move the mouse outside the OtsUserControl, there is flickering.

How can I fix this flickering problem?

BTW, the code to invoke it via RibbonButton goes through MVVM Light's RelayCommand mechanism.

I also have a file being shared on the SkyDrive.  When you ran the sample application, after the MainWindow has been loaded, click on one of the tree node with folder icon and click the expander button as you do in windows explorer. You will see no flickering. However if you select the same node and click the Toggle Expand button on the toolbar, you will see the usercontrol border flickering.

To view it, click the link below.
 [sample VS 2012 project showing the flickering problem](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=91bc9ec1e9a7cdee&id=91BC9EC1E9A7CDEE!483&Bsrc=Share&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&authkey=!AosMfoKduTfyp0U)

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: WPF does not flicker. something must be terribly wrong with your code and/or XAML.

Comment: Your comment does not help. Just search for WPF flickering, you will find some. Not all are due to bad coding.

Comment: dude, post the relevant code and XAML. if you think I'm not in a position to discuss WPF, please check my StackOverflow profile.

Comment: I just uploaded the sample project. Hopefully you can see the flickering and help me for a fix.

Comment: I just tested your project and I don't see any flickering.

Comment: Have you looked at it carefully? The flickering is not excessive, but it's there compared with no flickering at all if you click the expand toggle button WITHIN the usercontrol itself. 

Here is my environment: 

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit Service Pack 1

.NET Framework: 4.5.50709

BTW, what theme are you running? If you use the Windows Classic, you probably will see no flickering in this sample. Pick the Windows 7 Aero theme.

Comment: dude, that's not "flickering". That's just a blinking border probably caused by a style trigger related to keyboard focus. "flickering" is what you see in winforms, not in WPF. Please edit your question and change the title. Also include a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: I saw the border blinking/flickering MULTIPLE times after I clicked just once on the toolbar button for my REAL WPF application. However I cannot post the real code, only this sample showing off the same problem.

Comment: use Snoop to inspect the running application and check where changes are coming from (IE Styles / Templates / Triggers). then you can change that.

Comment: I used snoop before. However I don't know how to use it to catch where the blinking is from (Styles / Templates / Triggers). Can you teach or point to me how to?

Comment: inspect the borders, look for BorderBrush / Borderthicknesses. Then, with Snoop open and focused in these properties, click on stuff to cause the flicker and see how properties change in the Snoop window.

Comment: I saw no properties change in the Snoop window while clicking the toolbar button. I can force BorderThickness to be 0 to get rid of flickering, however that's not something I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Default `ListView` Template (extracted using Blend):

```
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" 
                                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                            RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" 
                                                            RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" 
                                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

The border blinks whenever the `IsMouseOver` or `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` are toggled.

If you don't want that, simply change these lines:

```
 RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" 
 RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
```

To:

```
 RenderMouseOver="False" 
 RenderFocused="False"
```

You will need to add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll` and add this xmlns:

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion however I still have the same problem. Where/which files should I change?